# Interface type inference

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

I have the following types:

```js
interface A { a: string }
interface B extends A { b: string }
interface C extends A { c: string }
```

I now want to write the following function that returns an `A`:

```js
function test(t: number): A {
    return t > 10
        ? { a: "a", b: "b" }
        : { a: "a", c: "c" };
}
```

This only works if I explicitly cast the returned objects to `A`, `B` or `C`, or if I create separate functions that explicitly return either a `B` or a `C` and use these to construct the object.

Is there any way the compiler can infer that the returned object is, in fact, a `B` or a `C` and therefore also an `A`, without me having to specify that?

Comment: More obviously to return `B` from `test`: `function test(): B`, because you  will can to write `var a: A = test();`

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov, of course, but `test()` needs to return an `A`, because `B` is not the only type it can return, as in this very simplified example. I updated the example to make it clear that there are multiple types that extend `A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like TypeScript does not infer the type of an object to be that defined by an interface.

The inferred type of `{ a: "a", b: "b" }` is `{ a: string, b: string }`, which can be used wherever an `A` or a `B` can be used, but it's neither `A` nor `B`, it's a different type.

So the answer is: no, the compiler will not infer `A` or `B`, it will infer something else, and a cast is necessary if the desired type is `A` or `B`.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that it's because TypeScript enforces additional constraints upon object literals regarding excess properties. If it's re-written like this, there is no error:

```
interface A { a: string }
interface B extends A { b: string }

function test(): A {
    const result = { a: "a", b: "b" };
    return result;
}
```

There is also the `suppressExcessPropertyErrors` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Comment: That's interesting, but it looks like `const result = { a: "a", c: "c" }` is also valid, so I'm assuming that in this case it simply ignores everything that's not defined in `A` instead of determining that `result` is a `B`, and therefore the function would be allowed to return an invalid object. I'm more interested in a type safe option, if one exists.

Comment: TypeScript just doesn't work like that. If something has the shape of interface  `A`, it's an `A` regardless of whether it extends `A` or not.

Comment: Just an observation: these kind of questions often pop up when you use object literals. Depending on what A and B are, you might use classes and create a `new A()`. In my experience, you will get better code intellisense/type checking.

Comment: @cartant, `{ a: "a", b: "b" }` actually has the shape of `B`, not of `A`, but it's cast to an `A` by the return type. Looking more into it, it looks like the issue is the fact that TypeScript **doesn't** determine the type of an object of a certain shape to be that defined by any interface, unless cast or used in a context requiring that interface. According to the compiler, the type of `{ a: "a", b: "b" }` is neither `A` nor `B`, but instead it's `{ a: string, b: string }`, which can be used wherever an `A` or `B` is required.

Comment: @Kokodoko, indeed, classes don't have this issue, since there's nothing to infer.